# I was gived a unique-key value by a hibernate mapping file for a column and i got a exception at debug level

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Here is my hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is my spring config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="org.openshares.billchecker.infrastructure.persistence.hibernate" />

    <bean
        id="dataSource"
        class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property
            name="driverClass"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />    
        <property
            name="jdbcUrl"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/billc?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8" /> 
        <property
            name="user"
            value="gaigeshen" />    
        <property
            name="password"
            value="gaigeshen" />    
        <property
            name="initialPoolSize"
            value="5" />
        <property
            name="acquireIncrement"
            value="5" />    
        <property
            name="maxPoolSize"
            value="15" />   
        <property
            name="minPoolSize"
            value="5" />    
        <property
            name="maxIdleTime"
            value="1800" /> <!-- 1800 Seconds -->
        <property
            name="maxStatements"
            value="50" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property
            name="dataSource"
            ref="dataSource" />
        <property
            name="configLocation"
            value="classpath:/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <property
            name="mappingDirectoryLocations"
            value="classpath:/org/openshares/billchecker/infrastructure/persistence/hibernate" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property
            name="sessionFactory"
            ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

Here is my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping
    package="org.openshares.billchecker.domain.model.area"
    default-access="field">
    <class name="Area" table="billc_area">
        <id name="id" column="area_id">
            <generator class="org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator" />
        </id>
        <property
            name="mid"
            column="area_mid"
            not-null="true"
            unique-key="uk_billc_area_mid"
            update="false" />
        <property
            name="name"
            column="area_name"
            not-null="true"
            length="15" />
        <property
            name="type"
            column="area_type"
            not-null="true"
            length="8">
            <type
                name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">
                    org.openshares.billchecker.domain.model.area.AreaType
                </param>
                <param name="type">12</param>
            </type>
        </property>
        <property
            name="zip"
            column="area_zip"
            length="10" />
        <many-to-one
            name="parent"
            column="area_parentid"
            foreign-key="fk_billc_area_parentid" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When i starting the tomcat server,there is a exception:

```
2015-06-08 15:53:57 DEBUG org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:251) create table billc_area (area_id bigint not null auto_increment, area_mid bigint not null, area_name varchar(15) not null, area_type varchar(8) not null, area_zip varchar(10), area_parentid bigint, primary key (area_id)) ENGINE=InnoDB
2015-06-08 15:53:58 DEBUG org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:251) alter table billc_area drop constraint uk_billc_area_mid
2015-06-08 15:53:58 DEBUG com.mchange.v2.log.slf4j.Slf4jMLog$Slf4jMLogger$DebugLogger.log(Slf4jMLog.java:198) com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@81db9f2 handling a throwable.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'constraint uk_billc_area_mid' at line 2
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1618)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1549)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyStatement.java:436)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-06-08 15:53:58 DEBUG com.mchange.v2.log.slf4j.Slf4jMLog$Slf4jMLogger$DebugLogger.log(Slf4jMLog.java:198) Attempted to convert SQLException to SQLException. Leaving it alone. [SQLState: 42000; errorCode: 1064]
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'constraint uk_billc_area_mid' at line 2
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1618)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1549)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyStatement.java:436)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-06-08 15:53:58 DEBUG com.mchange.v2.log.slf4j.Slf4jMLog$Slf4jMLogger$DebugLogger.log(Slf4jMLog.java:198) Testing a Connection in response to an Exception:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'constraint uk_billc_area_mid' at line 2
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1618)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1549)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyStatement.java:436)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-06-08 15:53:58 DEBUG org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:251) alter table billc_area add constraint uk_billc_area_mid  unique (area_mid)
2015-06-08 15:53:58 DEBUG org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:251) alter table billc_area add constraint fk_billc_area_parentid foreign key (area_parentid) references billc_area (area_id)
2015-06-08 15:53:58 INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.executer code here`ute(SchemaUpdate.java:267) HHH000232: Schema update complete
```

The schema updated succeed! But what's the mean this exception?Thanks!!

Comment: Hibernate created four sql statements:
1. create table billc_area (area_id bigint not null auto_increment, area_mid bigint not null, area_name varchar(15) not null, area_type varchar(8) not null, area_zip varchar(10), area_parentid bigint, primary key (area_id)) ENGINE=InnoDB

2.alter table billc_area drop constraint uk_billc_area_mid

3.alter table billc_area add constraint uk_billc_area_mid  unique (area_mid)

4.alter table billc_area add constraint fk_billc_area_parentid foreign key (area_parentid) references billc_area (area_id)

The exception was throwed when execute second statement

Comment: Are you sure that the dialect is right?

Comment: Can you please post your configuration file?

Comment: That is not the Hibernate dialect. That is the mysql version.

Comment: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Comment: I am already post the config file to this question

Comment: Change your driver class name property to  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

Comment: invalid property 'driverClassName' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]

The

Comment: I don't understand why hibernate builded the second sql statement for me?Because that i got the exception!

Comment: How many operations you are performing only creation or any thing else?The extra sql statement is 'alter table billc_area drop constraint uk_billc_area_mid' ,ryt?

Comment: This is the first time i create this table use hibernate,and finally,that table's schema is right,and it has the unique key named uk_billc_area_mid.Not anything else that i do.I just config-ed these 3 file and a Area class i created.

Comment: Yes,that sql statement is the second statememt.